# How to set the sliding image as a background image?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I'm using [Views Galleriffic](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_galleriffic) module in D7 site. Also I got the slider as i needed but still one more thing I need to work, i.e I wanna to set the sliding image (large image) as a background image.

I added the image field in views and added again the same image field in this field i rewrite the output as `<div class="myimage" style="background-image: url([file_url]);">field 1;</div>`. It doesn't works.

And also tried that rewriting the image field1 as (without adding it second time)

```
<div class="myimage" style="background-image: url([file_url]);">&nbsp;</div>
```

This also doesn't works.

If anyone knows,please share your answer and let me know.